# Installing ROS Industrial on INDIGO

Tags: ros-industrial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can ROS-IND be installed on INDIGO?  `apt-get install ros-indigo-industrial-desktop` does not work for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207573/installing-ros-industrial-on-indigo/) by [cmackin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22119/cmackin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the packages in ROS-Industrial can be installed on ROS Indigo.

At present (2015-04-22) the [industrial_core](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_core), [abb](http://wiki.ros.org/abb) and [universal_robot](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot) packages have been officially released and can be installed using `sudo apt-get install ..`.

The [fanuc](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc) and [motoman](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman) packages have not yet been released, but can be build from source. The Indigo page for [fanuc_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver?distro=indigo) lists the steps required to do that. The same steps can be used for the motoman packages, see [How can I use Motoman stack with ROS Indigo?](http://answers.ros.org/question/191233/how-can-i-use-motoman-stack-with-ros-indigo/) for more info.

The `ros-industrial-DISTRO-desktop` package has not been released into Indigo yet, so that is why you cannot install it using `apt-get`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1